# Visual Basic, How do I read each row in a datagrid?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid called DataGridView1, column A contains a name, column B contains a path to a file. How do I run some code for each row? What is the correct terminology for traversing a datagrid in this way?

Example of what I need:

```
For each row in DataGridView1
 MessageBox.Show DataGridView1.ColumnA.text & "," & DataGridView1.ColumnB.text
```

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You were nearly there, you need something like the following:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
        MessageBox.Show(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "," & row.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
    End If
Next
```

EDIT:

You need to check if the row.IsNewRow is not True if your DataGridView allows adding rows.