# Function get specific cell value in gridview , vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

What i want to do is get a value from the data grid. Example:
a button onclick will change the color of the cell if the cell value is "test".
i have the coding on how to change color but how to do the loop to search the value.
Considering that only 1 column has a cell with the value test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ..

```
For y As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    For x  As Integer = 0 to DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1

         If Datagridview.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value = "test" Then 

             DataGridView1..Rows(y).Cells(x).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red

         End If

    Next

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop thru the rows and search for the text.

in this one you find out how to loop

[Visual Basic, How do I read each row in a datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031704/visual-basic-how-do-i-read-each-row-in-a-datagrid)

additionally if you have multiple columns and want to loop thru them too then you have to nest this peace in another loop, something like

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                If row.Cells(i).Value.ToString = "test" Then DataGridView1.Item(i, row.Index).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next

    Next i
```

Good luck