# I am trying to add a variable number of items to a SQL database from a datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a windows form application in VB that will count the rows in the datagridview control and insert them into a SQL database. The problem is that there aren't the same number of rows in the datagridview each time the button is clicked.

What I need to happen is each datagridview row will insert the item name and item quantity to the database.

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Button22_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button22.Click
    Dim myconnect As New SqlConnection
    myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SEA-1800033547\SQLEXPRESS;database=operations;


    Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    mycommand.Connection = myconnect


    mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO odrcmp (CustName, CustAddress,Phone,email,item1,item1qty,item2,item2qty,date) VALUES (@custname, @custaddress, @phone, @email,@item1,@item1qty,@item2,@item2qty,@date)"
    myconnect.Open()

    Try

        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@custname", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = customername.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@custaddress", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = customeraddress.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = phonenumber.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = email.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Label1.Text



        For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & i, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & i & "qty", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                mycommand.Parameters.Clear()
            Next
        Next

        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Success")
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    myconnect.Close()




End Sub
```

When I don't have the mycommand.Parameters.Clear() line in the code, it will say that is still looking for the scalar value for item2, which leads me to believe that somewhere the loop is messed up.

When I add mycommand.Parameters.Clear() it says it is looking for @custname. I'm sure that is because of the code looping back through.

Comment: I've just removed my original answer, as I don't think it was right. What is the reason for having nested loops? You have the `For i` loop, and then also the `For each` loop.

Comment: First, this line "mycommand.Parameters.Clear()" in the loop removes all your parameters. That's why it says it requires @custname. Second, why do you use a nested?

Comment: @SteveLovell  I did the nested loops in an attempt to get it to work. When I just use the "for i" loop, it errors out saying "must declare item1 scalar variable. With the "For Each Row" loop, I can't figure out how to get the variable to work with item. When I use "item" & row" it says: System.InvalidCastException: 'Operator '&' is not defined for string "item" and type 'DataGridViewRow'.'. I appreciate you working with me on this!

Comment: @handoko Thank you for the insight. In regards to the loop, I was just trying to get it to work through the rows.

Comment: Ok, I assume that the `count -1` is to handle the 'add new row'. Remove one of the loops, and let us know if you get the same error regardless of how many rows are actually in your data grid. Is the `odrcmp` set to allow `NULL`s in `item2` and `item2qty`?

Comment: Will attempt a proper answer later, in the meantime, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031704/visual-basic-how-do-i-read-each-row-in-a-datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an easy way to test this, but the following is a reworked version of your loop. The second half, which attempts to set the parameters for any unused item fields may not be needed, as I believe they should default to `NULL` in any case. If the `unusedRows` loop isn't required, you could get rid of the `rowNo` variable and use the row index instead.

```
Dim rowNo as Integer
rowNo = 1
For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & rowNo, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & rowNo & "qty", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Row.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        rowNo = rowNo + 1
    End if
Next row

'Possible you don't need the remainder, I think the unset params should default to this anyway.

Dim unusedRowsNo as Integer
Dim maxRows as Integer

'Change the following to how many rows you want to handle in the DataGrid.
maxRows = 10 

For unusedRowNo = rowNo to maxRows
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & unusedRowNo, SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DBNull.Value
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & unusedRowNo & "qty", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DBNull.Value
Next unusedRowNo
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: This code does the same as the above code from Raffaello.It continues to look for item3.

Comment: It's definitely possible. It's slow progress because we're not sat next to each other. Also because I'm a very amateur .net developer. Does your `CommandText` agree with the value assigned to `maxRows`?

Comment: It does match the command text. I went back and made sure I had everything entered the way you provided. Now it is saying Invalid Column name for item1, item1qty, item2,item2qty,date.

Comment: Ah, now that sounds like a conflict between the table structure and the SQL. Does the table have all the relevant columns?

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I had been adding and deleting two tables named ordcmp and ordcmp (everyone is entitled to having a moment...I just seem to have more than most other people) . I wrote the connection for the wrong one after putting the columns in the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Now i understand better how your program works;

Here's my solution

Remember to set DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRow = False (otherwise the For loop will take into account also the Last Row of the DataGridView1 (the Add New Row))

```
Dim CNN As New SqlClient.SqlConnection

    Try

        CNN.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SEA-1800033547\SQLEXPRESS;database=operations"

        CNN.Open()

        Dim cmdCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = CNN.CreateCommand
        cmdCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ordcmp (CustName, CustAddress, Phone, email, item1, item1qty, item2, item2qty, date) VALUES (@CustName, @CustAddress, @Phone, @email, @item1, @item1qty, @item2, @item2qty, @date)"

        cmdCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = customerName.Text
        cmdCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = customerAddress.Text
        cmdCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = phonenumber.Text
        cmdCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = email.Text
        cmdCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 20).Value = Label1.Text


        For iRow As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

            Dim DGVR As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(iRow)

            cmdCommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & (iRow + 1), SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DGVR.Cells(1).Value
            cmdCommand.Parameters.Add("@item" & (iRow + 1) & "qty", SqlDbType.Int, 9).Value = DGVR.Cells(2).Value

        Next

        cmdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        CNN.Close()
        CNN.Dispose()
        MessageBox.Show("Success")


    Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
        CNN.Close()
        CNN.Dispose()
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

    End Try
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on opening the connection in the try, catch block.I don't think I'm being as clear as I need to be and I apologize. To answer your question, the columns in the datagridview are 0(for the item name) and 2(for the quantity). I appreciate the code, but I will eventually have more than 2 items (I'm thinking the limit will be 10 items). Let's say my customer buys 1 order of brownies and 1 order of cookies.This will appear as two different rows in the datagridview. I want to put the brownies in as item1 and the quantity as item1qty. The cookies will be item2, etc, etc.

Comment: I edited my previous answer; now i think it's working as you wanted

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: I tried this one and it threw an error because it was looking for Item3. I'm not even sure this is possible anymore lol

Comment: Surely because you entered 3 rows in the datagridview. Try with only 2 rows in the datagridview and it will work. Obviously you need to handle every number of rows present in the DataGridView: i suggest you to limit the maximun number of items an user can insert (let's say 10), and to design ordcmp table with 10 items columns and 10 itemsqty columns (i,e, ordcmp will have columns such as item1, item1qty, item2, item2qty, ..., item10, item10qty). All this columns should be designed to have a zero default value (so the insert command could work properly).

Comment: Surely I didn't enter 3 rows. Also, when I set the allowusertoaddrow to false, The button that I used to add rows to the datagridview wouldn't add rows.

Comment: So your user enters data directly in the DataGridView1? Not through other controls (i.e. some textboxes to enter item names and quantities, so you could add a new row programmately)? If so, leave the allowusertoaddrow set to true, but remember that also the new row (the blank row that the user can edit) counts as one. Let's say that the user entered 3 items, the DataGridView1 will now have 4 rows. The loop in the code will look for 8 columns (item1, item1qty, item2, item2qty, ..., item4, item4qty). That's the reason why i suggested to declare columns with 0 default value.